Set up direnv for microsamba
Today I had top spent up some hours to set up direnv for 'microsamba'.
Since due to the reduced installation there are no acticate scripts to source and I had troubles to set up the correct layout.
For instance
layout_micromamba() {
  export MAMBA_HOME="${HOME}/Data/micromamba"
  export MAMBA_EXE="${HOME}/.local/bin/micromamba"
  export MAMBA_ROOT_PREFIX='/home/abu/Data/micromamba'
  local my_shell=$(basename ${SHELL})
  local env_name="$1"
  __mamba_setup="$("${MAMBA_EXE}" shell hook --shell "${my_shell}" --root-prefix "${MAMBA_ROOT_PREFIX}" 2> /dev/null)"
  __mamba_activate="$("${MAMBA_EXE}" activate "${env_name}")"

  eval " ${__mamba_setup}"

  if [ -n "$1" ]; then
    # Explicit environment name from layout command.
    eval activate ${env_name}

  elif (grep -q name: environment.yml); then
    # Detect environment name from `environment.yml` file in `.envrc` directory
    eval "$mamba_hook; micromamba activate $(grep name: environment.yml | sed -e 's/name: //')"

  else
    (>&2 echo No environment specified);
    exit 1;

  fi;

  unset __mamba_setup
  unset __mamba_activate
}

puts an output error
direnv: loading ~/test-env/.envrc
action: hool not in {init,deinit,reinit,hook,activate,deactivate,reactivate}
Run with --help for more information.

'micromamba' is running as a subprocess and can't modify the parent shell.
Thus you must initialize your shell before using activate and deactivate.

    To initialize the current bash shell, run:
        $ eval "$(micromamba shell hook --shell=bash)"
    and then activate or deactivate with:
        $ micromamba activate
    
To automatically initialize all future (bash) shells, run:
    $ micromamba shell init --shell=bash --prefix=~/micromamba

Supported shells are {bash, zsh, csh, xonsh, cmd.exe, powershell, fish}.

critical libmamba Shell not initialized
direnv: export ~PATH

I tried several methods but none worked out.

After hours I found the solution. The microsamba activate has to be involed with the shell function microsamba which gets generated after the invoke of the micromamba shell hook command. Since I found no solution in the web I would like to share the right layout for direnv. Put this code into your ~/.config/direnv/direnvrc file:
#
# micromamba
#
# touch a '.envrc' file in your project directory and insert the following code in it:
# layout micromamba <your-environment-name>

layout_micromamba() {
  # adjust the target to your installation of the BINARY micromamba
  export MAMBA_EXE="${HOME}/.local/bin/micromamba"
  # adjust the target to the installation prefix
  export MAMBA_ROOT_PREFIX="${HOME}/micromamba"
  # find the shell in use
  local my_shell=$(basename ${SHELL})
  local env_name="$1"
  __mamba_setup="$("${MAMBA_EXE}" shell hook --shell "${my_shell}" --root-prefix "${MAMBA_ROOT_PREFIX}" 2> /dev/null)"

  eval " ${__mamba_setup}"

  if [ -n "$1" ]; then
    # Explicit environment name from layout command
    # DO NOT USE $MAMBA_EXE , instead the shell function 'micromamba' which got generated after '__mamba_setup'.
    micromamba activate ${env_name}

  elif (grep -q name: environment.yml); then
    # Detect environment name from `environment.yml` file in `.envrc` directory
    micromamba activate $(grep name: environment.yml | sed -e 's/name: //')

  else
    (>&2 echo No environment specified);
    exit 1;

  fi;

  unset __mamba_setup

}




